# "Pre-reserve" to express retaining something in advance

Tags: word-request, prefixes

*Reserve* means to retain something **and** to keep something for a particular purpose or time.

I want to use *reserve* but with the meaning of retaining something initially/in advance/before the time.

As prepaid, for example, in which you usually pay for something, but *here*, you pay in advance for that thing.

I wonder if there is no such thing as "pre-reserve" since [Google](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=active&source=hp&ei=q3bBXPHDOcTcwQKDrYjIDQ&q=pre+reserve+meaning&oq=pre-reserve+&gs_l=psy-ab.1.4.0j0i30l7j0i8i30l2.508.4581..7572...0.0..0.244.1725.0j12j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..35i39j0i131j0i10.qZ4BhZV3tJw) showed no result of it. I think this is because "reserve" has the retaining *in advance* implicitly, but as we use this term in my language, I want to know if there is a one in English.

For example, I say: "In order to get an appointment at the salon, I should make a **reservation ahead in time**." After a while, I would say: "Okay, so we made a **reservation**, now we only need to wait."

The example is to state the difference in my point of view between the two. I would substitute "reservation ahead in time" with "pre-reserve" if it exists.

Comment: If you explain better the intended meaning of "pre-reserve", we might be able to provide better explanations. What is the difference between "reserve" and "pre-reserve"?

Comment: reserve x in advance

Comment: @Lambie _ So it is possible but can't be substituted with "pre-reserve", right?

Comment: It just would not be used because if you reserve a seat, for example, it's already before something. But we do use the redundant expression: reserve in advance.

Comment: @Lambie _ I think we use it in a redundant way too. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your salon example, we would normally just say "making an appointment". You have scheduled time with one or more professionals, and it is generally part of their job to take care of anything that might need to be reserved.

One of the most common uses of "reserve" in English is "Making a dinner reservation at a restaurant". You are reserving the use of a table at the restaurant, possibly days or months in advance. You would normally request a "Reservation for two" or a "Reservation for six", where the number is understood to mean the number of persons. You can reserve a hotel room, seats on a plane, theater tickets, admission to a tourist attraction, and many other things. In all of these cases it is understood that you are reserving a time-slot in the future.

When you *permanently* reserve something, we often call that "buy". For example sports stadiums sometimes have booths or "[boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxury_box)" for watching the game. (A fancy glass-front room with furniture and probably a sink, refrigerator, private bathroom, tv, and food-delivery service). You can rent a box for one game, you can "buy" the box for a season, and sometimes you can permanently buy the box. Buying the box reserves use of a specific room during each game at that stadium. If you don't attend the game the room remains empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alsee! Great answer and a clear explanation with additional details and examples.

Answer (score 1):

> Reserve means to retain something and to keep something for a particular purpose or time.

You are correct.

---

> ... "reserve" has the retaining in advance implicitly ...

You are correct again.

---

> I want to know if there is a one in English

The term "pre-reserve" does not make much sense. And its meaning seems to be quite identical with "reserve", so there is no need of it.

Comment: Thank you very much, virolino! I have updated the question, and I hope it is more clear now although your last statement is very reasonable.